# How to clone a group which includs the loaded .obj models?

Tags: javascript, three.js

i created a empty THREE.Object3D() named as groupChair. And then, load 3 obj files and add into groupChair in the callback function. then add the groupChair into scene. it works. but why i cannot clone this groupChair object?

below is the code:

```
        var groupChair = new THREE.Object3D();
        var cloneChair;
        var cushion;
        var backrest;
        var frame;

        var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );

        //load the 1st obj file
        loader.load('model-stuff/chair/obj/cushion.obj', function( object ) {
            object.traverse( function ( child ){
                if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                    child.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
                        map: textureColorForCushion, 
                        roughness: 3,
                        metalness:0.6,
                        blending: THREE.NormalBlending,
                        shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
                        envMap: textureCube,
                    });
                    child.receiveShadow = true;
                    child.castShadow = true;
                }
            });
            cushion = object;
            groupChair.add( cushion );
        }, onProgress, onError);

        //load the 2nd obj file
        loader.load('model-stuff/chair/obj/backrest.obj', function( object ) {
            object.traverse( function ( child ){
                if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                    child.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
                        map: textureColorForCushion, 
                        roughness: 3,
                        metalness:0.6,
                        blending: THREE.NormalBlending,
                        shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
                        envMap: textureCube,
                    });
                    child.receiveShadow = true;
                    child.castShadow = true;
                }
            });
            backrest = object;
            groupChair.add( backrest );
        }, onProgress, onError);

        //load the 3th obj file
        loader.load('model-stuff/chair/obj/frame.obj', function( object ) {
            object.traverse( function ( child ){
                if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                    child.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
                        map: textureColorForFrame, 
                        roughness: 0.9,
                        metalness:0.4,
                        blending: THREE.NormalBlending,
                        shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
                        envMap: textureCube,
                    });
                    child.receiveShadow = true;
                    child.castShadow = true;
                }
            });
            frame = object;
            groupChair.add( frame );
        }, onProgress, onError);

        scene.add( groupChair );

        //clone groupChair object, but it doesn't work
        cloneChair = groupChair.clone();
        cloneChair.position.set(30,0,0);
        scene.add( cloneChair );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code example, you are cloning the groupChair object before all objects are loaded. TO wait until all object are loaded, you can make use of the `THREE.LoadingManager`. Also for every object you are loading, you should add a seperate loader.

```
    var groupChair = new THREE.Object3D();
    var cloneChair;
    var cushion;
    var backrest;
    var frame;

    var loader1 = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );

    //load the 1st obj file
    loader1.load('model-stuff/chair/obj/cushion.obj', function( object ) {
        object.traverse( function ( child ){
            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                child.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
                    map: textureColorForCushion, 
                    roughness: 3,
                    metalness:0.6,
                    blending: THREE.NormalBlending,
                    shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
                    envMap: textureCube,
                });
                child.receiveShadow = true;
                child.castShadow = true;
            }
        });
        cushion = object;
        groupChair.add( cushion );
    }, onProgress, onError);

    var loader2 = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
    //load the 2nd obj file
    loader2.load('model-stuff/chair/obj/backrest.obj', function( object ) {
        object.traverse( function ( child ){
            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                child.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
                    map: textureColorForCushion, 
                    roughness: 3,
                    metalness:0.6,
                    blending: THREE.NormalBlending,
                    shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
                    envMap: textureCube,
                });
                child.receiveShadow = true;
                child.castShadow = true;
            }
        });
        backrest = object;
        groupChair.add( backrest );
    }, onProgress, onError);

    var loader3 = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
    //load the 3th obj file
    loader3.load('model-stuff/chair/obj/frame.obj', function( object ) {
        object.traverse( function ( child ){
            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                child.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
                    map: textureColorForFrame, 
                    roughness: 0.9,
                    metalness:0.4,
                    blending: THREE.NormalBlending,
                    shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
                    envMap: textureCube,
                });
                child.receiveShadow = true;
                child.castShadow = true;
            }
        });
        frame = object;
        groupChair.add( frame );
    }, onProgress, onError);

    scene.add( groupChair );

    manager.onLoad = function(){

        //clone groupChair object, but it doesn't work
        cloneChair = groupChair.clone();
        cloneChair.position.set(30,0,0);
        scene.add( cloneChair );

    }
```